# How to start a sequence from a particular number like 5000 or 6000?

Tags: sequence, odoo, odoo-11

I am wondering if in Odoo you can start a sequence number from some specific number, like 60001 or 65001?

Currently, I set up an auto-increment sequence which starts from 0. Every time a record is created, it increase the value by 1.

My problem is, I want to start the sequence from 2501. How can I change the starting index of the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the following code in the data file to give starting value for the sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
     <data noupdate="1">               
       <record id="sequence_id" model="ir.sequence">
          <field name="name">name_of_sequence</field>
          <field name="code">code_of_sequence_for_identification</field>
          <field name="padding">8</field>
          <field name="number_next">2501</field><!-- (Starting Number) -->
          <field name="number_increment">1</field>
       </record>                
     </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value for "Next Number" to your desired value.